# ordenar mi lista aleatoria

Tags: python

tengo este ejercicio en python es un bingo el cual eh generado de forma simple pero lo que no me resulta es ordenar mi lista que son aleatorias

```
[{'nombre': 'a', 'tarjeta_bingo': [88, 55, 82, 75, 86, 82, 50, 19, 57], 'puntaje': 3}, {'nombre': 'b', 'tarjeta_bingo': [28, 49, 37, 48, 70, 87, 54, 88, 86], 'puntaje': 1}, {'nombre': 'c', 'tarjeta_bingo': [63, 24, 85, 62, 14, 39, 78, 11, 34], 'puntaje': 5}]
```

pero la ayuda que necesito es ordenar esta lista que tengo pero por el ultimo valor que es el puntaje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se entiende mucho el pedido. ¿Cuál es la salida que necesitás, una lista con qué?
Acá te escribo una función que te daría el nombre del ganador, asumiendo que el ganador es el que tiene el puntaje más alto. Fijate que lo que vos tenés en realidad es una lista que adentro tiene un diccionario por cada participante, por lo cual vas a tener que recorrer los elementos de la lista (los diccionarios), y dentro de ese recorrido ir operando con los elementos de los diccionarios.

```
listaDeDiccionarios = [{'nombre': 'a', 'tarjeta_bingo': [88, 55, 82, 75, 86, 82, 50, 19, 57], 'puntaje': 3}, {'nombre': 'b', 'tarjeta_bingo': [28, 49, 37, 48, 70, 87, 54, 88, 86], 'puntaje': 1}, {'nombre': 'c', 'tarjeta_bingo': [63, 24, 85, 62, 14, 39, 78, 11, 34], 'puntaje': 5}]

def ordenar(lDd):
    ganador = ""
    valorMasAlto=0
    for d in lDd:
        if d['puntaje']>valorMasAlto:
            valorMasAlto = d['puntaje']
            ganador = d['nombre']
    return ganador
print (ordenar(listaDeDiccionarios))
```

Comment: pues si es exactamente lo que tengo, ya que es lo que me piden como ejercicio pero mi dilema es llegar a leer lo de dentro de la lista que es el diccionario, muchas gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: enserio muchas gracias ya tengo una mejor idea te lo agradezco

Comment: @PaulodelAguila si esta respuesta te sirvió, márcala como aceptada. Además, también puedes votar a favor, para ayudar a identificar las respuestas que te fueron útiles.

Answer (score 1):

Tu lista, es una lista de diccionarios, lo que buscas es ordenar la misma por una de las claves de estos diccionarios (`puntaje`). La forma más sencilla de hacerlo es mediante:

```
nuevalista = sorted(lista, key=lambda x: x['puntaje'])
```

`sorted()` ordena la lista, obteniendo el valor por el cual ordenar mediante la función anónima `lambda x: x['puntaje']` que no es más que decir: recuperar el valor de  `porcentaje` de cada elemento

Comment: muchas gracias señor patrico eh estado buscando una solucion a eso incluso indague y lei esa parte pero aun asi sigo sin poder ordenarla me sale un error, ya que habia creado un meto para poder sacar el puntaje y mandar un print para que el ganador salga arriba algo sencillo pero aun asi no me sale seguire intentando, muchas gracias